Homological criterion for finite generation
Let $G$ be a (discrete) group.  Assume that for all finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules $M$, the homology group $H_1(G;M)$ is finitely generated.  Does it follow that $G$ is finitely generated?
More generally, I’m trying to find a “homological” criterion for finite generation, so any variant of the above would also be of interest.

G is finitely generated if and only if the augmentation ideal is finitely generated.  I believe this is the same as H^1(G,-) preserving direct limits.

Or, more generally, group is of type $FP_n$ iff $H^k(G, -)$ commutes with filtered colimits for $k \leq n$.

I recommend Bieri's Queen Mary notes, "Homological dimension of discrete groups".
